# Output and use array elements from a REST Api call in php

Tags: php, rest

I am calling a REST Api to get data using curl in php. It gives me the list of data/contents in the api in Array php format.

I was able to get single element value using `$resultArray[0]['nid'][0]['value'];`. But my goal is to get elements in all contents in the api.

Say I want to get the following elements in the nested arrays.

```
$resultArray[0]['nid'][0]['value'];
$resultArray[0]['vid'][0]['value'];
$resultArray[0]['cid'][0]['value'];
```

And use these values in a loop too.

I am trying to search how I can do it loop, and if anyone can provide sample code, that would be appreciated.

Update:
This is the sample result of var_dump:

```
 array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(38) {
    ["nid"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(1)
      }
    }
    ["vid"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(2)
      }
    }
    ["cid"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(3)
      }
    }
    ["field"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["target_id"]=>
        int(4)
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(38) {
    ["nid"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(11)
      }
    }
    ["vid"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(22)
      }
    }
    ["cid"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(33)
      }
    }
    ["field"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["target_id"]=>
        int(44)
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(38) {
    ["nid"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(111)
      }
    }
    ["vid"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(222)
      }
    }
    ["cid"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(333)
      }
    }
    ["field"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["target_id"]=>
        int(444)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to use these elements values in a loop.
Say my expected result is.

```
Test1 = "1", "2", "3"
Test2 = "11", "22", "33"
Test3 = "111", "222", "333"
```

These equivalent numbers should be comming from the element `nid, vid, cid`.

I dont just want to assign/echo these values in the result as I have array[100s] in one api call.

Comment: Please show us an example of the data (do a var_dump() of the result) and show us what the expected result would be. You should also show us what you've tried and what result you're currently getting. Currently, your question is very unclear. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have updated my issue.

Comment: Tried this test `$result = $resultArray;
foreach ($resultArray as $key => $values) {
   $result[$key] = implode($values);
}` but getting result `PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your array is a multidimensional array, you need to have nested `foreach` loops:

```
$test = 1;
foreach ($resultArray as $items) {
    // Echo the current test number
    echo "Test{$test} = ";

    $values = [];
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // Get the correct value.
        if (array_key_exists('value', $item[0])) {
            $values[] = $item[0]['value'];
            continue;
        }

        if (array_key_exists('target_id', $item[0])) {
            $values[] = $item[0]['target_id'];
            continue;
        }
    }

    echo '"' . implode('", "', $values) . '"' . "\n";
    $test++;
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/fnHlV

Comment: will try it now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JohnReyTanquinco - If it solved your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: I have an issue on this, as I have not include other elements in the `var_dump` sample result. I have some elements that has `target_id` instead of `value`, so maybe theres a way to specify the element variable.

Yes I will accept it once everything is okay, no worries :)

Comment: I have updated the `var_dump` result. This is the result when I have other elements with different label instead of `value`... `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: target_id in..`

Comment: @JohnReyTanquinco - That's moving the goal post and is quite disrespectful. I took time to give you an answer to your original question and actually don't have time sitting here and updating the answer to fit your changes. If you have other params, just check  which exists in the inner foreach and use the correct one. And for next time, include _all_ info in the original question.

Comment: Im not really good at executing/making test of loops, especially with multidimentional array, as im still new/learning php. So apologies for these follow ups, and I believe you are also making answers to my issues. And I really appreciate that!

Comment: @JohnReyTanquinco - I've updated the answer. If you have other key names, just add a new `if`-statement and you're set.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a BIG help!

Comment: could you please vote up for this question if you feel like this is a valid concern. thanks!